# How to fix icon to make nearby with text on top navigation in wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have an issue about trying to make an icon nearby with text on top navigation in custom theme wordpress but still not luck.You can check out my theme on [URL Development](http://dev.galerigadget.com). How I can fix it like my concept below?
[image: top navigation concept]

**Its style.css here:**

```
.main-navigation2 a {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 7px 0 0 6px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 43px;
    color: #FFF;
    background: url(img/arrow.png) no-repeat scroll right / 20% 20%;
    width: 74px;
    background-position-x: 96%;
}
```

Thanks before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the corrected CSS

```
.main-navigation2 a {
     background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("img/arrow.png") no-repeat scroll right center / 15px 8px;
     color: #fff;
     display: block;
     line-height: 43px;
     margin: 7px 0 0 6px;
     padding: 0 20px 0 0;
     text-decoration: none;
     width: auto;
}
```